# control access to a resource with two application instances

Tags: python, concurrency, semaphore

I have a use case where i have to count the usage of my application that which feature is used most. I am storing all my statistics in a file. Each time application closes it will write the statistics to that file.

Application is standalone and is in the server, and multiple people can use the application at the same time by running the application(So its like multiple copy of application will be running at different places).

So the problem is if multiple people try to update the stat at the same time there are chances of getting the false statistics(concurrency control problem). So how can I handle such situations in python?

I store the followiing data in my stat file::

```
stats  = {user1 : {feature1 : count, feature2 : count, etc..},
          user2 : {feature1 : count, feature2 : count, etc..}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [portalocker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/portalocker), it's a great module that gives you a portable way to use filesystem locks.

If you are confined to one platform, you could use platform-specific file-locking primitives, usually exposed via python standard library.

You could also use a proper database but it seems like a huge overkill for the task at hand.

**EDIT:** seeing that you are about to use threading locks, don't! Threading locks (mutexes or semaphores) only prevent several threads in the same process from accessing shared variable, they *do not* work across separate processes, especially independant program instances! What you need is a file-locking mechanism, not thread-locks.

Comment: Hey is there a way to lock the file using the built in python module? Coz I want to minimize the extra third party packages being used in my app.

Comment: there is — what is your target platform and python version?

Comment: Am using python 2.7 with ubuntu-11.04 machine.

Comment: then use [`fcntl.lockf`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf). beware — there are some corner-cases when it won't work, such as over NFS or if some other app attempts to use the file without locking, it will succeed (this is advisory lock, not mandatory); these are probably un-important to you so lockf should do the job just fine.

Comment: Ok thanks! so it is linux based and not portable right? So most probably i will go with portalocker.

Comment: fcntl will work on most srv-based unix systems, i.e. all modern unix systems, but yes, it is generally non-portable. if you need portability, portalocker is the best i've seen so far. generally, file locking is a very hard problem with no good solution. that's why under some specific circumstances there's no other choice but to use a proper database, or reimplement rdbms as a separate process of your app that will manage the access to the file, but for something as simple as a "write the stats" is completely unnecessary. i'd say stick with portalocker or with fnctl if you don't need Windows.

Comment: @user2109788 did this solve your problem? if yes, can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like its a flavor of the readers-writers problem which is extended to transactions from the database. I would create a SQL-transactional class which is primarily responsible for the CRUD operations with your database. I would then have a flag which could be locked and released in a very similar way to mutex locks, this way you are able to ensure that no two concurrent processes are in their critical section (performing an UPDATE or INSERT into the DB) at the same time.

I also believe there is a readers-writers lock which specifically deals with controlling access to a shared resource, which might be of interest to you.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

In your code where the shared resource can be used by multiple applications, use Locks

```
import threading
mylock = threading.Lock()

with mylock:
     ....
     #access the shared resource
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give a try! Will it work if i try to use same resource from different different applications!?

Comment: And also is there a way to specify the time out value?

Comment: I am not very familiar with threading concept. So i have a very basic question, If the resource is locked and if the other process wants to write to that resource, so will that other process waits for resource to be released or just exits?

Comment: No these locks won't work on the process level.
Read more on https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look at it and suggest the answer.